# Finding historical flight arrival data

Tags: late-arrival

How can I find historical flight arrival data for AF149 for September 29, 2017? I need to file a claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do: flightradar24.com
You need a Gold account to access flight data up to 365 days: you can sign up for 7 days trial